# Optimizing PHP function

Tags: php, function, optimization

My language bar generation function looks like that. It works, but, feels like, it's not optimal way and this function has bunch of extra lines that can be removed. How you'd minify it?

```
public function generateLangs($url, $curlang, $langs) {
    $i = 0;
    $countlng = count($langs);
    foreach ($langs as $lang) {
        if (strstr($url, '?')) {
            if (strstr($url, 'lang')) {
                $newurl = preg_replace('&lang=(\w+)&', 'lang=' . $lang, $url);
            } else {
                $newurl = $url . '&lang=' . $lang;
            }
        }
        else {
            $newurl = $url . '?lang=' . $lang;                
        }
        $result = '<a ';
        if ($curlang == $lang) {
             $result .= 'class="active" ';
        }
        $result .= 'href="' . $newurl . '">' . $lang . '</a>' . "\n";
        if ($i != $countlng - 1)
            $result .= ' | ';
        echo $result;
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use `$result[] = '<a ...'; ...; echo implode( ' | ', $result)` but it wouldn't bring you anymore performance increase... I think you're good with that

Comment: There's a code review site: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Which lines make up the "bunch of extra lines that can be removed"?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you could make the language value a parameter of the URL by using a simple placeholder, like `%s` or `%lang%`:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/site/?lang=%lang%';
$newurl = str_replace('%lang%', $lang, $url);
```

You can either do this or you should encapsulate the logic to replace some query parameter of an URI into a function of it's own and use built-in functions in there instead rolling your own (e.g. `parse_url`, `parse_str`, ...).

Similar to that, same applies to your output, you could use the existing index (0 based I guess) and therefore streamline the whole:

```
public function generateLangs($url, $currentLanguage, $languages)
{

    $urlPattern = preg_replace('~^(.*[?&]lang=)([a-z]+)((?:&.*)?)$~', '\1%lang%\3', $url, 1, $count);
    $count || $urlPattern .= '?lang=%lang%';
    unset($count);

    foreach ($languages as $i => $lang)
    {
        $newUrl = str_replace('%lang%', $lang, $urlPattern);
        printf("%s<a href=\"%s\"%s>%s</a>\n", $i ? ' | ' : '', $newUrl, 
                $curlang === $lang ? ' class="active"' : '', $lang);
    }
}
```

The key point more or less is that you group code next to each other that belongs to each other. This more or less automatically reduces the complexity of the code and therefore often as well it's length. But take care that length is not that crucial, it's more important that you can read it cleanly.